# Implementing field/column level security in a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, security, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET Web API that allows clients to return details of People and associated data.
There are a number of non-fixed roles in the system (it's multi-tenanted) and each Role has access to particular fields e.g. Admin could see Date of Birth, non-admin can't.

The structure of the application is:

Client  Controllers > Business/Service layer > Repositories > Database

Data access is currently being managed through a combination EntityFramework for Add/Update/Delete and Dapper for Queries.

My question is: is there a excepted standard/common of approach of filtering data at field level going to the client, and returning from a client before updating models in the database? Ideally if there was some sample code or application to demonstrate the approach.

My initial thoughts on this are to filter the ViewModels before they get sent to the client and perform checks before updating the EntityFramework models, but this seems disjointed. Also I'm not 100% on the best approach to this either way.

Other possibles I have considered are:

- Use a formatter to remove data before being sent to client, and a custom security attribute to filter data before hitting the controller action.
- Move away from EntityFramework and implement my own secure Data Access Layer to handle all of this
- Implement the security at the database level
- A ViewModel per entity per role, although I have discounted this as with non-fixed roles this can blow up quite quickly.

I'm not aware of any frameworks available that offer field-level security but lots of commercial products offer very configurable field-level security e.g. SalesForce, Microsoft CRM, etc.. and essentially I would like to implement something similar but on a smaller scale.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution, did you ever get an answer?

Comment: I have half a solution, specifically tackling the reader side of things. 
On the read of side of things I have set up a permission system where roles are linked to columns. Then when reading the data I blank out data where the user/role does not have permission to view the data. The end result is custom JSON string that is sent the client.
Also I am using a memory cache to store details of the permissions to prevent hitting the database every time a user requests data.

Comment: I'm looking for similar solution too. Still there are no good solutions ?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to implement security at field level. Have you improved this? or do you have any additional recommendation?