# Field-level security with Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, encryption

I have a field/column called `Id` that is a hidden field in an ASP.NET MVC view. When an AJAX call POSTs it to a Web API action, is it possible to ensure the value wasn't changed on the client?

I've looked at this question: [Implementing field/column level security in a Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384007/implementing-field-column-level-security-in-a-web-api) and this one: [Property/Field level security with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929910/property-field-level-security-with-rest-api). The former has no answer while the latter has no accepted answer.

One solution could involve having a pair of hidden fields: one with the value and a second with the encrypted value; you'd POST both, decrypt the 2nd hidden field and see if it matches 1st unencrypted hidden field.

Is there a library or something to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you encrypt it, you can use the decrypted value, removing the need for an unencrypted copy. But this sounds like an XY problem. Please explain the use case. What you probably need is something like row-level security, i.e. validating whether the calling user is allowed to access and/or update the record identified by the id.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks. Use case is: we don't want anyone to modify the field `Id` in the browser; this would allow them to access someone else's records. Having the encrypted field sounds like perhaps the easier way to go, though we've used the row-level security elsewhere in the app.

Comment: _"this would allow them to access someone else's records"_ - well there's your problem. Why don't you stop them from editing someone else's records? Anyway ids are just strings, so find some decent encrypting/decrypting code and put it in an accessible helper method, calling them wherever you output an id or receive one. Asking for libraries is off-topic anyway.

Comment: Hmm. Nice! Get to the root of the XY problem, rather than find the solution 1st. 
Thanks, @CodeCaster :) No wonder you have 115K rep! Please throw that in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should work with the expectation that users can and will change the values submitted, and in fact almost *allow* them to do so. If, for example, you don't want user `A` to be able to delete record with `ID` '1', you should put validation to look up the current user versus the id. I would do this by making your viewmodel object implement `IValidatableObject`, implement a `Validate()` method, and `ModelState.IsValid()` from within your controller. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This is not your object or exact use-case, but here's a sample that shows the pattern:

```
    public class BillableUnbillableEdit : IValidatableObject
    {
        public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //TODO: any other validation before changing and saving this record?
            var db = new WorkorderEntities();

            if (db.WorkOrders.Any(i => i.Title == Title && i.Id != WorkOrderId))
                yield return new ValidationResult($"A WorkOrder with the same title already exists.", new[] { "Title" });
        }
    }
```

If you *really* want to do this against the `Id` with a token or something, I would say generate a hash on the fields you do not want to change, or a new guid, stick that into a session variable *and* deliver it in the object to the view, and then compare the 2 against one another when they come into the controller.